# Passing object parameters form one class to another

Tags: c#

I have a class that basically gets a value form a function that connects to a database the parameter passed is UserID which is stored in an object of type array index 0 which works - when I print the value in the console, UserID outputs the expected value

```
class DatabaseClass
{
     private String[,] dbUsersResults = new String[1, 3];

     //**************************** SIGN IN USER ****************************
     public bool dbSignIn(String username, String password)
     {
         UserDetails[] ud = new UserDetails[1];

         Boolean isValid = false;

         dbRead("SELECT * FROM user_credentials WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'", "signin");

         if ((dbUsersResults[0, 1] == username) && (dbUsersResults[0, 2] == password))
         {
             ud[0] = new UserDetails();

             ud[0].UserID = dbUsersResults[0, 0];
             ud[0].Username = username;
             ud[0].Password = password;
         }
     }
 }
```

Now my problem is, when I try to call the UserID object ud, in class UserDetails  object ud, array 0, from a different Class, the parameter is blank

the code of other class from where I am calling the UserID parameter is below

```
       UserDetails[] ud = new UserDetails[1];
       ud[0] = new UserDetails();

       Console.WriteLine(ud[0].UserID);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using .NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn’t answer my query

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Aren't you using ud array variable locally?

Comment: And make sure you never get the three musketeers to sign in, "D'Artagnan" will crash your system :)

Comment: 1. Use paramatized inputs, not string concatenation. 2. Don't ever store passwords like that in clear text. That's a really bad security vulnerability on so many levels. 3. You are creating a brand new array instance, and adding a new userdata instance to it. This is not the same bit of memory you wrote to before.

Comment: Give the details of dbRead method

Comment: @user2520212 that's why it was a comment and not an answer :-). But I felt obliged to mention it, especially dealing with login code it's potentially a serious flaw in your application. The other related comments underneath also make good points regarding problems with special characters such as apostrophes in your input strings and the security of your passwords. Regarding your actual question, I think you need to study the concept of variable "scope". You can give two variables the same name if they're in different contexts (e.g. different classes), and then they don't share any data.

Comment: So for instance in the code above, you declare `UserDetails[] ud` within the `dbSignIn` method. That means its scope is limited to that method - you cannot access it at all outside that method, it simply doesn't exist. You'd have to declare it with at a wider scope (e.g. class level, and maybe make it public) and/or return it from the method - see Peter's answer below which covers your options quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two totally **separate and unrelated** `ud` variables: one in method `dbSignIn()`, and one in your calling code. There is no "magic" that makes the compiler understand that you want these to be in fact the same, so they are separate.

There are multiple ways to solve this, e.g. (but not limited to):

- make `ud` a public member of `class DatabaseClass` and use that from the calling side.
- make `ud` a private member of `class DatabaseClass` and provide a public method or property to access it
- make method `dbSignIn()` return the `ud` variable (instead of a boolean) and use that from the calling side.
- give method `dbSignIn()` an `out UserDetails[] ud` parameter and use that from the calling side.

---

Apart from all this, I wonder why you are using an array of UserDetails, and not a single object. There is only one username + password at a time being processed, so it would suffice to declare it as `UserDetails ud` followed by this:

```
ud.UserID = dbUsersResults[0, 0];
ud.Username = username;
ud.Password = password;
```

Comment: I have redirected this post to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572035/accessing-object-parameters-added-in-an-array