# Accessing object parameters added in an array

Tags: c#

I want to know how to access ListArray 1 and print one of the parameters of the object added to that ListArray

Main Program:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 {


class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
         List<TaskDetails> taskDetails = new List<TaskDetails>();

         Console.Write("Please enter User ID: ");
         string i = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("Please enter username: ");
         string s = Console.ReadLine();

         ud.SetDetails(i, s);

         int cnt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         for (int x=1; x <= cnt; x++)
         {
             Console.Write("Please enter title for Task: " + x + " ");
             string title = Console.ReadLine();

             TaskDetails td = new TaskDetails();
             td.SetTask(i, title);
             taskDetails.Add(td);
         }
         PrintDetails pd = new PrintDetails();
     }
 }    
 }
```

Task Details

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class TaskDetails
    {
        private string UserID { set; get; }
        private string TaskTitle { set; get; }      
        private List<TaskDetails> TaskList = new List<TaskDetails>();


        public TaskDetails() { }

        public List<TaskDetails> GetTaskList
        {   
            get { return TaskList; }
        }

        public void SetTask(string userID, string taskTitle)
        {
            this.UserID = userID;
            this.TaskTitle = taskTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

this is class I am using  to access the ArrayList in class TaskDetails, I want to be able to access the object in the array by index and to one of its parameters

```
 namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class PrintDetails
    {
        public void print(int i)
        {
            TaskDetails qw = new TaskDetails();

            List<TaskDetails> MyList1 = qw.GetTaskList;

            Console.WriteLine(qw.GetTaskList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem you're facing is that when you create a new TaskDetails, you initialise a new version of TaskDetails, which starts off empty. If you feel that a separate class is necessary for the PrintDetails you could have something like the following:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class PrintDetails
    {
        public void Print(List<TaskDetails> taskDetails, int i)
        {
            var taskDetail = taskDetails[i];

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
                "UserID: {0}, TaskTitle: {1}",
                taskDetail.UserID,
                taskDetail.TaskTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main function, call it as follows:

```
PrintDetails pd = new PrintDetails();
pd.Print(taskDetails, i);
```